# Why is my code not entering the else statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

see i have a situation over here. See in my code, which you can see below, everything works fine until the assignement to the variable "fd" of 'int' type. Even though fd != -1 it does not enter the else statement. Can anyone explain me why and maybe fix it?

```
int mostra(char *nomeFicheiro) //Mostra o conteÃºdo dum ficheiro; Retorna 1 com sucesso, 0 com erro
{
    char aux[4000];
    int cont = 0, i = 0, resultado = 2;
    int fd = open(nomeFicheiro, O_RDONLY); //abre o ficheiro 'nomeFicheiro' em modo RDONLY no descritor fd
    printf("fd = %d\n\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1) 
    {
        resultado = 0; 
        printf("resultado = %d\n", resultado);
    }
    else
    {
        //o programa nÃ£o entra aqui, tudo para cima funciona, mas nÃ£o entra neste else
        printf("b");
        read(fd, aux, sizeof(aux));
        printf("c");
        int teste = conta(nomeFicheiro);
        while (aux[cont] != EOF || i <= teste)
        {
            if (aux[cont] == '\n') {
                printf("%d", i); i++;
            }
        }
        printf("d");
        write(1, aux, cont);
        printf("e");
        resultado = 1;
    }
    close(fd);
    printf("after close, resultado = %d\n\n", resultado);
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not `-1` and it does not execute the `else` ?

Comment: What *is* the value of `fd`? If it is not `-1`, then the `else` will be executed.

Comment: It's entering the `else`. Your `printf`s aren't displayed because they have no trailing `\n` and aren't being flushed.

Comment: I am using char *argv[] so i'm using linux and passing out arguments directly from the terminal when executing the program. If i pass a name of a file that exists on the directory, the variable "fd" normally takes the value of 3 but never -1, so i know that's not the problem. It just doesn't enter the else statement

Comment: And please note how the code *should be* formatted

Comment: @interjay the printfs don't show up because the else statement is not being, let's say "used"

Comment: The `printf`s are not being showed because of output buffering most likely. Add some `\n`s

Comment: `aux[cont] != EOF` this condition is incorrect. It can't be `EOF`

Comment: Guys using the \ns actually helped but now it doesn't go any further than the printf("c\n");

Comment: Because you have infinite loop - see above

Comment: @EugeneSh. thx m8, do u have any idea on how to solve this? I would like to go through the array until the end of file character

Comment: [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) is returning a value. Use it.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, it's fully functional now :D

Comment: "until the end of file character" **NNNNNOOOO** end of file **is not a character!** You need to review the classes with end of file and C streams. I repeat because it's important: **end of file is not a character!**

Comment: @pmg thx dude but it is already working, nonetheless i will look into that, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the final function after being changed, thanks everyone :D

```
int mostra(char *nomeFicheiro) //Mostra o conteÃºdo dum ficheiro; Retorna 1 com sucesso, 0 com erro
{

char aux[4000];

int cont = 0, i = 0, resultado = 2;

int fd = open(nomeFicheiro, O_RDONLY); //abre o ficheiro 'nomeFicheiro' em modo RDONLY no descritor fd

if (fd == -1) {resultado = 0;}

else
{

int var = read(fd, aux, sizeof(aux));

write(1, aux, var);

printf("\n");

resultado = 1;

}

close(fd);

return resultado;

}
```